# Is regularity is preserved under reversal?

Tags: proof-writing, automata, computational-mathematics, regular-language, formal-grammar

When talking about languages and regular languages.

Can I say that reversal preserved regularity since if the language L is regular, we can generate it by right linear grammar.

Therefore, the reversal language will be the left linear grammar version of L.

Is that true to say?

Comment: Yes, although if you’re writing up a proof, you should offer a little more detail on exactly what you mean by ‘the left linear grammar version’.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thank you

Comment: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is regular, to prove this, for any regular language, L, you can find a DFA and by reversing  the transitions in the DFA you will get another DFA that accepts the reverse of L.

Comment: By reversing the transitions of a DFA you don't get a DFA but a NFA. But this suffices to prove that the reversal is regular.